# Select last 30 days with a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking for the number of Mon,Tues, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun in the past 30 days. Can I select the last 30 days date and day of week without an actual database table? Something like

```
SELECT --everything between
convert(date,GETDATE()), DATENAME(DW, GETDATE())
--and
convert(date,GETDATE() - 30), DATENAME(DW, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Umm... What? Are you selecting from a temp table or variable table or what? Either way, the answer is yes, but your code is not exactly ideal.

Comment: @Tejs - I made a change to my question.  I am looking for how times each day of the week get hit in the past 30 days.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT convert(date,GETDATE()) sDate, DATENAME(DW, GETDATE()) sDayofWeek
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-1,sDate), DATENAME(DW, DATEADD(DAY,-1,sDate))
    FROM CTE
    WHERE sDate > GETDATE()-29
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: @user54197 -- You might want to look at my answer -- faster.

Comment: @Hogan - That's right, but my answer was for the original question, not the one that is right now. In any case, your answer is correct for the new question, and the op should go with it

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I wonder what the OP actually wants.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a couple of ways to do it.

1. You could fill a temp table, using a loop and INSERT statements, and then select the contents of the table.  You could create a table-valued UDF to do this, in fact.
2. You could also create 30 SELECT statements, and UNION them all together.  But, frankly, I think you're better off with option 1.

ETA:  Thinking about it, if all you want is the number of each day of the week in the past 30 days, you can probably do that just with some math, without returning 30 records.

There are 4 instances of each day of the week in any 30 day period, plus 2 extra days.  So all you really need is to know what day of the week the first day in your period is, and the second day.  Those days of the week have 5 instances.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cteCount AS (
    SELECT DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) dw, 1 ix 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, -ix, GETDATE())), ix+1 FROM cteCount WHERE ix<30
)
SELECT dw, COUNT(1) cnt FROM cteCount GROUP BY dw
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple solutions:

```
SELECT ... From ... WHERE date > DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Also, I think this statement will work with MySQL:

```
select date_sub(now(),interval 30 day)as Datebefore30days;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty lazy and just load a temp table and then do a group by select on that temp table

```
DECLARE @tmpDates TABLE (calDate DATETIME)
DECLARE @beginDate DATETIME
SET @beginDate = DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())
WHILE @beginDate < GETDATE()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tmpDates ([calDate]) VALUES (@beginDate)
    SET @beginDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@beginDate)
END


SELECT DATEPART(dw,[calDate]) AS [weekDay], COUNT(1) AS [dayCount]
FROM @tmpDates
GROUP BY DATEPART(dw,[calDate])
```

Answer (score 1):

Number of times each day of the week got hit in the last 30 days:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,GETDATE())+' 5 times' as results
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()))+' 5 times'
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(day,-2,GETDATE()))+' 4 times'
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(day,-3,GETDATE()))+' 4 times'
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(day,-4,GETDATE()))+' 4 times'
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(day,-5,GETDATE()))+' 4 times'
UNION ALL
SELECT DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(day,-6,GETDATE()))+' 4 times'
```

This really is about dividing 30 by 7

---

This gives me

```
results
Thursday 5 times
Wednesday 5 times
Tuesday 4 times
Monday 4 times
Sunday 4 times
Saturday 4 times
Friday 4 times
```

Comment: Unusual and... correct. :) But if I were you, I would parametrise it to show how the results were obtained.

Comment: I mean, to show it in the script itself, not just verbally in the answer. :)

Comment: @Andriy - Not sure what you mean... you want inline comments?  Also, if correct why no up-vote?  :D

Comment: No upvote, because it is you who solved the problem (performed the actual calculations), not your script. :) I think it would be better if you included the calculations in the script, not the ready answers.

Comment: @Andriy - That seems like bad programming to me.  If a calculation is always going to equal 4 or 5 why have the calculation in the script?  Just slows it down.  30 divided by 7 is 4 with 2 remainder.  We all learned this when we were 8 years old.

Comment: @Hogan: True. My point is, your solution has little value (in *my* opinion). It does solve the immediate problem, and if I were the original poster, I would at least upvote it. But being in this situation a potential answerer of this question, I find myself free to estimate the fellow answerers' posts by some other criteria. And in particular I find your solution, although clever, incomplete, and thus not worth *my* upvote. I by no means pretend to be a model as an upvoter, just stated my reasoning, that's all.

Comment: @Hogan: To clarify further why I think the calculation should be included: the 30 could easily become 50 or 100. That is, it just could be a parameter, in which case the calculations would just *have* to be included.