# how to select last 30 days mysql record and group by each day

Tags: php, mysql

i have in mysql DB some records and want to get last 30 days records by "token" and group by each day.

my DB column like this:

[image]

tanks!

Comment: Could you please add some more rows and the desired result. Also what is the type of column dateview?

Comment: what is the *group by each day* means? what do you want to get for that group?

Comment: Have you used your fav search engine to look up `GROUP BY date in MySQL`? If not, that's where you should start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select last 30 days with a sql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981971/select-last-30-days-with-a-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your date as Y-m-d and run the SQL below.

SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE token = 'vitC' AND dateview BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() GROUP BY dateview